# Javascript HTML table shifting when I press checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

When I press the checkbox table's elements are not in inline. I am just hiding class="box". Do i need to write a special format? As a default, they are inline but when i press check box, they are shifting. The column Status is not in order. N/A' location is changing.

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    
    
    <script language="JavaScript">
    
        function showMe(cls) {
            var chboxs = document.getElementsByName("c1");
            var vis ="none";
            for (var i = 0; i < chboxs.length; i++) {
                if (chboxs[i].checked) {
                    vis ="block";
                    break;
                }
            }
            var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(cls);
            for (let e of elements) {
                e.style.display = vis;
            }
        }
    </script>
    
    </head>
    
    
                    <br>
                    <table class="header" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="c1" onclick="showMe('box')">Show Result
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                    
                    <table class="uniqueborder" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                    <td class="uniqueborder" width="90%" align="center" bgcolor="#F3F3F3"><b>Event</b></td>
                    <td class="uniqueborder" width="10%" align="center" bgcolor="#F3F3F3"><b>Status</b></td>
                    </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="uniqueborder" align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; ">Test </p></td>
                              <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="uniqueborder" align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; ">Test </p></td>
                              <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table><table class="box" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border-right:1px solid #CBCBCB; padding-left:2px; padding-right:2px"align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; ">Test </p></td>
                              <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                        </tr>
    
                    </tbody></table><table class="box" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="uniqueborder" align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Test input:</span></p></td>
                              <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="uniqueborder" align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Expected</span></p></td>
                              <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                        </tr>
    
                    </tbody></table></table>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: You need to include the CSS in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm getting you right; the problem is that you are using display: none,but the initial value of the display is '', wich this chang it should work.

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    
    
    <script language="JavaScript">
    
        function showMe(cls) {
            var chboxs = document.getElementsByName("c1");
            var vis ="";
            for (var i = 0; i < chboxs.length; i++) {
                if (chboxs[i].checked) {
                    vis ="block";
                    break;
                }
            }
            var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(cls);
            for (let e of elements) {
                e.style.display = vis;
            }
        }
    </script>
    
    </head>
    
    
                    <br>
                    <table class="header" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="c1" onclick="showMe('box')">Show Result
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                    
                    <table class="uniqueborder" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                    <td class="uniqueborder" width="90%" align="center" bgcolor="#F3F3F3"><b>Event</b></td>
                    <td class="uniqueborder" width="10%" align="center" bgcolor="#F3F3F3"><b>Status</b></td>
                    </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="uniqueborder" align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; ">Test </p></td>
                              <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="uniqueborder" align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; ">Test </p></td>
                              <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table><table class="box" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border-right:1px solid #CBCBCB; padding-left:2px; padding-right:2px"align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; ">Test </p></td>
                              <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                        </tr>
    
                    </tbody></table><table class="box" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="uniqueborder" align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Test input:</span></p></td>
                              <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="uniqueborder" align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Expected</span></p></td>
                              <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                        </tr>
    
                    </tbody></table></table>
    
    </html>
```

**EDIT**
With this code you "hide" the N/A without using display, you have to change the calsses I added a class name hideEl

```html
<html>
    <head>
    
    
    <script language="JavaScript">
    
        function showMe(cls) {
            var chboxs = document.getElementsByName("c1");
            var vis =1;
            for (var i = 0; i < chboxs.length; i++) {
                if (chboxs[i].checked) {
                    vis =0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(cls);
            for (let e of elements) {
                e.style.opacity = vis;
            }
        }
    </script>
    
    </head>
    
    
                    <br>
                    <table class="header" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="c1" onclick="showMe('hideEl')">Show Result
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                    
                    <table class="uniqueborder" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                    <td class="uniqueborder" width="90%" align="center" bgcolor="#F3F3F3"><b>Event</b></td>
                    <td class="uniqueborder" width="10%" align="center" bgcolor="#F3F3F3"><b>Status</b></td>
                    </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="uniqueborder" align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; ">Test </p></td>
                              <td class="uniqueborder hideEl" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="uniqueborder" align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; ">Test </p></td>
                              <td class="uniqueborder hideEl" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table><table class="box" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border-right:1px solid #CBCBCB; padding-left:2px; padding-right:2px"align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; ">Test </p></td>
                              <td class="uniqueborder hideEl" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                        </tr>
    
                    </tbody></table><table class="box" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="uniqueborder" align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Test input:</span></p></td>
                              <td class="uniqueborder hideEl" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="uniqueborder" align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Expected</span></p></td>
                              <td class="uniqueborder hideEl" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                        </tr>
    
                    </tbody></table></table>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: If I say "none", The Value will not change, I am just making show/hide so when I press checkbox, N/A position should be under Status.

Comment: @Ugur I had update the answer, guess that is what you want, "hide" the N/A.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but, the problem is when i click checkbox N/A shifting to left. the row(3,4,5) should be removed as an example  when I click the checkbox thats working but mean time N/A shifting. In your second example, just status part disappearing.

Comment: @Ugur you want to hide the words?  and keep the rows? or you want to hide the row?

Comment: Checkbox only hides if class="box" that is ok but when you click my script, you can see that N/A moving to left, It should not move from under Status. Of course it should be hidden when checkbox not checked

Comment: This is the last One, I dont know if you are explaining wrong or I'm not getting you, but this is what I understood that you wanted to achive-> https://codepen.io/Carlos1232/pen/bGEojMM?editors=1000